# VS Setup Project - Installing Assemblies to GAC and starting a service that uses them all in one installation

Tags: dll, windows-services, installation, windows-installer, setup-project

I've read every stackoverflow article on MSI installations, but I cannot find the solution to my problem:

I have a VS2010 solution with 5 projects, all targeting .NET 2.0:

- DLL A, no project references
- DLL B, references DLL
- A Windows Forms App, references DLL B
- Windows Service, references DLL B
- Setup Project

DLL A and DLL B are set up as to be installed to the GAC at install time. I'd like to start the service once the installation has finished, but according to what I've read, the assemblies are not registered until the very last step. I have proven this by attempting to start the service on the AfterInstall event of my ServiceInstaller class and I get the following error:

> Error 1001. Could not load file or
>   assembly 'DLL_B', version 1.0.0.1,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=5e297270603814f4' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system
>   could not find the file specified.

But of course, once installation is complete, I can manually start the service and it runs fine. Also, in Windows XP, I can usually have the service started at application launch (I have a checkbox with Launch Application as the last step of the installer). But in Windows 7, permissions are no longer elevated at that time and starting the service throws an error.

How can I achieve the installation and starting of the service **without forcing a reboot**? To quote my client: "Its 2011 now and that shouldn't be necessary.", and I agree whole-heartedly.

Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is to use a custom action which runs after InstallFinalize in InstallExecuteSequence table. This custom action should use the [msidbCustomActionTypeAsync and msidbCustomActionTypeContinue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368071%28VS.85%29.aspx) flags so it runs in a separate process after the installation is finished.

This cannot be done with a Visual Studio setup project, but there are a lot of alternatives: [Orca](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370557%28VS.85%29.aspx), WiX, a commercial setup authoring tool etc.

Comment: Any CA scheduled after InstallFinalize won't have elevated privileges. This might just work if UAC is off, but it's not good practice, IMO.

Comment: This is true. But it can be easily avoided by elevating the installer UI (by using a bootstrapper for example) or an EXE custom action with an application manifest which requests elevation.

Comment: I marked Cosmin's answer as the correct one because it was closest, simply because of the part where he said "This cannot be done with a VS setup project, but there are a lot of alternatives." I chose to use InnoSetup. I found it very easy and it is flawless for my needs. The installer is screaming fast and does exactly what I need it to do.

Answer (score 2):

This is a well-known issue with the GAC. One option might be to use two separate installers and daisy-chain them. This is the way we have chosen to get around the problem of deploying Microsoft VC runtimes on Vista and later. If you use the merge modules, any services that depend on them won't start. So in effect you put your GAC-destined components in a pre-installer whose transaction will be completed and committed before you run a second install that installs and starts the services that depend on them. Ugly, I know, but better than a reboot.

Answer (score 1):

I worked around this issues slightly differently: I installed my assemblies not only in GAC, but also into the Application Folder. My GAC-bound assemblies were already found as dependencies, so I put those into GAC (and those indeed end up there only after all custom steps executed). I also added same assemblies as primary output to the Application Folder, where my InstallHelper DLL with custom actions also resides. This way during installation local copy from Application Folder is used.